# Determine if there exists a normal subgroup of $\Bbb R$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^2 = \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Determine if there exists a normal subgroup of $\Bbb R$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^2 = \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$.

I’m not sure if there is one so I’m trying to figure out what would happen if there was such a map. So suppose that $\varphi : N \to \Bbb Z^2$ where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $\Bbb R$ is a bijective homomorphism. Then I would have to have that $\varphi(e_N) = e_{\Bbb Z^2}$ and $\varphi(x \cdot y)= \varphi(x) \varphi(y).$ Also since we’re supposing that $\varphi$ is bijective $\varphi(g)=\varphi(g’) \implies g=g’$.

The identity of $\Bbb Z^2$ seems to be $(1,1)$? I assume that the binary operation is multiplication since we’re not given one(?). If so then I suppose that $x \mapsto(x,x)$ would work for as $\varphi$ since it’s surjective and $\varphi(g)=(g,g)=\varphi(g’)=(g’g’) \implies g = g’$ it would be injective.

But is this homomorphic? It seems odd that I’m not given any binary operations how would I know what operation $N$ is equipped with and also $\Bbb Z^2$ could be equipped with say addition and then $(1,1)$ wouldn’t work as the identity?

Comment: When we talk of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group, then we consider addition as the group operation. The set $\mathbb{Z}$ with multiplication is not a group.

The same is true for $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, we consider coordinate-wise addition. 

With that in mind, the homomorphism you talk of should be additive, so $\varphi(x + y) = \varphi(x) + \varphi(y)$.

What is the identity in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?

Does this help you enough to solve the problem?

Comment: The group operation on both $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Z^2$ is $+$, not $\cdot$ (at least unless another exotic operation is specified). It can't be $\cdot$, since neither $\mathbb R$ nor $\mathbb Z^2$ have multiplicative inverses for all elements.

Comment: With that in mind, it is true that your map $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z^2:x\mapsto(x,x)$ is an injective homomorphism, but it is far from surjective (can you see why?).

Comment: Hint: I would try to construct an injective (but not surjective) homomophorphism the other way $\mathbb Z^2\to \mathbb R$. Think about where to send the generators $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. You want them to be "very separate" in some sense.

Comment: Yes I’m only considering pairs/vectors where each component is the same. So $(x,y)$ for $x \ne y$ are not considered at all which indeed makes $x \mapsto (x,x)$ far from surejctive.

Comment: @Kolja The identity in $\Bbb Z^2$ should then be $(0,0)$ so $\varphi(e_N)= (0,0)$.

Comment: Wouldn’t $\varphi : \Bbb Z^2 \to N, (x,y) \mapsto x+y$ work? It’s surjective and additive?

Comment: @JimingLe Your idea doesn't work since it's not injective, e.g. $\varphi((-1,1))=\varphi((1,-1))=0$. You need the ideas given in the two answers for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the map $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}, (m,n)\mapsto m+n\sqrt{2}$.

This map is injective so the image is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

There are other linear combinations that work obviously. If you let $(m,n)\mapsto am+bn$, you just need to make sure that $a,b$ aren't rational multiples of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Because $(\mathbb R, +)$ is abelian, so every subgroup of $(\mathbb R, +)$ is normal subgroup.

Let $G=\{(a,0)\mid a\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $H=\{(0,b)\mid b\in\mathbb Z\}$, $\mathbb Z^2$ is isomorphic to direct product of $G$ and $H$(or direct sum as $\mathbb Z$-module).

Let $f:\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb R$ is monomorphism(if there exists), then $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$ must be $\mathbb Z$-linear independent.

We know $1, \pi$ are $\mathbb Z$-linear independent. So $f:\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb R, f(a,b)=a+b\pi$ is monomorphism, and $\mathrm{Im}f$ is normal subgroup of $\mathbb R$ which is isomorphic with $\mathbb Z^2$.